# Linking and communication to AutoCAD in C++

Tags: c++, autocad

How can i open the AutoCAD application and send commands to that in C++?
 In the *VB* it's possible by *CreateObject* and *GetObject* functions.

Comment: So you'll have to translate the VB code to C++. The respective functions are [CoCreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615.aspx) and [QueryInterface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78xw8kzk.aspx).

Comment: I need to a complete example for this topic .can you help me?

Comment: A complete example wouldn't be very helpful, since you don't know [COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363.aspx). It is mandatory to understand COM before you can interface with applications that offer their programming interfaces by way of COM. Asking for sample code is also not the type of question to ask on stackoverflow (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, you need to use [CoCreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `CreateObject` and [CoGetObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms678805(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of `GetObject`.

Here is some sample code, adapted from this [sample of Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216686):

```
// Initialize COM for this thread...
CoInitialize(NULL);

// Get CLSID for our server...
CLSID clsid;
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"AutoCAD.Application", &clsid);

if(FAILED(hr)) {
  return -1;
}

// Start server and get IDispatch...
IDispatch *pAcadApp;
hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pAcadApp);
if(FAILED(hr)) {
  return -2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.It was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use C# instead of C++, the .Net syntax is much more friendly than the C++ if you start to deal with COM pointers.

Here is an example. You can always create a .Net CLI library and wrap your C++ code so you can use it from .Net.

```
void LaunchACAD()
{ 
    try
    {
        //Connect to a running instance
        AcadApp = (AcadApplication)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(
        "AutoCAD.Application"); 
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // starts last run acad version
        System.Type acType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AutoCAD.Application", true);   

        //  ("AutoCAD.Application.17.1"); // starts 2008
        //  ("AutoCAD.Application.17.2"); // starts 2009

        AcadApp = (AcadApplication)System.Activator.CreateInstance(acType);
    }

    AcadApp.Visible = true; // by the time this is reached AutoCAD is fully functional
}
```